# How do I read a file into an array and then sort the data?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So far, I've found a few ways to read the text file into an array and was able to display it on the screen successfully.
 What I have a problem with is how I sort the array from there. Sorting the text file was simple enough but when I tried to combine both, I couldn't get it to work.
 Here is what I've gotten so far:

```
int main()
{
   string players[30];
   ifstream inData("chessplayers.txt");
   if (inData.is_open())
   {
     for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
     {
       sort( players, players+i);       
       if (getline(inData, players[i]))
       {        
         cout << players[i] << endl;
       }
       else
       {
         break;
       }
    }
    inData.close();
  }
  else
  {
    cerr << "Failed to open file.\n";
  }
  system("pause");    
  return 0;
}
```

Can anyone help point me in the right direction? My assignment is to be able to read the text into an array and then sort that array.

Comment: `My assignment is to be able to read the text into an array and then sort that array.` Why are you sorting while you are reading in the data?

Comment: If you're referring to that random sort code I shoved in there, that was just my frustration. I actually need the text read into the array first and afterwards, manipulate the array by sorting it and doing whatever else I need.

Comment: for education purposes, check the library function qsort and what it requires.

Comment: @pizza : This is C++, not C -- `std::sort` _is_ the correct function to use.

Comment: well, for didactic purposes it's perhaps better to try implementing sorting algorithm manually?

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys. @Vlad- I'm not even sure where I should start the coding for a manual sort, you see. I'm actually very new to C++, well coding in general, so I'm still wrapping my head around it.

Comment: It is homework, it is better to point to things that the poster can learn from, rather than doing it for him.

Comment: Try breaking the problem into smaller parts and write a program to solve it. Reading a file into an array. Sorting an array with no elements, 1 element, 2 elements, etc.

Comment: @All How about building a heap while reading numbers from the file and later extracting them from the heap like in heapsort? Will that be more/less efficient?

Answer (score 1):

It is a good idea to separate different actions into functions. This makes your code cleaner, easier to read, and more modular.

For example, in this problem, you have three distinct things going on: reading your data into a file, sorting it, and printing it. Write your own functions to read the data in and print it. You know there is already a function to sort, so use that.

Here is an example (using a little bit of C++11), that uses techniques that you might not be "allowed" to use, but it gives you a good starting point to learn what you need to modify in your own code.

Notice that in main, the code is self-documenting: it says to read the players from a file, sort them, then print them.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <deque>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

typedef std::deque<std::string> PlayerContainer;

PlayerContainer getPlayersFromFile(std::string filename)
{
  PlayerContainer players;

  std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());

  std::string player;
  while (getline(ifs, player))
    players.push_back(player);

  return players;
}

void printPlayers(PlayerContainer const& players)
{
  // (this is the only part that depends on C++11)
  // for each player in players
  for (auto const& player : players)
    std::cout << player << '\n';
}

int main()
{

  std::string filename("chessplayers.txt");

  PlayerContainer players = getPlayersFromFile(filename);

  sort(players.begin(), players.end());

  printPlayers(players);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I'm starting to understand how it functions after reading that. You've been a great help, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Dont sort while reading the data. Put the sort function outside reading:

sort(players, players+30);

And if you're wondering about overloading dont, cause std::string provide it's own overloaded <, >, =, etc, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've tried typing the code outside the reading as you suggested but nothing happened. The program did run however, its like the code doesn't do anything. Perhaps I put it in the wrong spot? Where exactly should I type it?